# Can 'hoursAvailable' for 'ContactPoint' be used in JSON-LD?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I have a Schema.org `Organization` and I would like to support opening hours in it. Is it possible with JSON-LD?

I have seen `hoursAvailable` property on `ContactPoint`, but it seems to support Microdata only.

Comment: Ẁhat makes you think that it’s only for Microdata?

Comment: this: https://schema.org/hoursAvailable (JSON-LD tab)

Answer (score 0):

All Schema.org properties can be used in all syntaxes.

The examples for a property are only informative. If examples are only provided in one syntax, it doesn’t mean that this property can’t be used in the other syntaxes; it just means that no one converted the examples yet.

So you can use the [`hoursAvailable` property](http://schema.org/hoursAvailable) in JSON-LD.

Comment: I was trying to do that as per example 1 here: https://schema.org/OpeningHoursSpecification but on this validation tool: https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool I got an error saying "Duplicate field closes is not allowed." and "Duplicate field opens is not allowed."

Comment: @Bartosz: Did you change example 1? When I copy-paste the JSON-Ld into Google’s SDTT, I don’t get this error.

Comment: No, I took OpeningHoursSpecification from Example 1 and pasted it into Organization schema under contactPoint/hoursAvailable

Comment: @Bartosz: Interesting, I can reproduce it. My guess is that it’s a bug in Google’s SDTT. If you care about this issue, you could create another question (including the JSON-LD example that gives this error) to see if maybe someone sees an error or knows more etc.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to add hoursAvailable as a property of ContactPoint, of Person, to specify office hours using JSON-LD. http://linter.structured-data.org/ did not complain, but https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool did report errors. I found that if I only provided a single value for hoursAvailable, I did not have any reported errors:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "breadcrumb": 
    {
        "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
        "itemListElement": [
        {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 1,
            "item": 
            {
                "@id": "http://example.com/",
                "name": "One"
            }
        }
        ]
    },
    "mainEntity": 
    {
        "@type": "Person",
        "contactPoint" : 
        {
            "@type": "ContactPoint",
            "contactType": "customer service",
            "url" : "http://example.com/",
            "hoursAvailable": 
            {
                "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
                "dayOfWeek": "http://schema.org/Monday",
                "validFrom": "2018-01-08",
                "validThrough": "2018-04-13",
                "opens":  "09:30:00",
                "closes":  "11:00:00"
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I did not pursue that solution further. I decided to describe my office hours as a service using the following markup, and google's Structured Data Testing Tool did not report any errors.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
    "@context": "http://schema.org",
    "@type": "WebPage",
    "breadcrumb": 
    {
        "@type": "BreadcrumbList",
        "itemListElement": [
        {
            "@type": "ListItem",
            "position": 1,
            "item": 
            {
                "@id": "http://example.com/",
                "name": "One"
            }
        }
        ]
    },
    "mainEntity": 
    {
        "@type" : "Service",
        "url" : "http://example.com/",
        "hoursAvailable": [
        {
            "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
            "dayOfWeek": "http://schema.org/Monday",
            "validFrom": "2018-01-08",
            "validThrough": "2018-04-13",
            "opens":  "09:30:00",
            "closes":  "11:00:00"
        },
        {
            "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
            "dayOfWeek": "http://schema.org/Tuesday",
            "validFrom": "2018-01-08",
            "validThrough": "2018-04-13",
            "opens":  "09:30:00",
            "closes":  "11:00:00"
        },
        {
            "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
            "dayOfWeek": "http://schema.org/Wednesday",
            "validFrom": "2018-01-08",
            "validThrough": "2018-04-13",
            "opens":  "15:30:00",
            "closes":  "17:00:00"
        },
        {
            "@type": "OpeningHoursSpecification",
            "dayOfWeek": "http://schema.org/Thursday",
            "validFrom": "2018-01-08",
            "validThrough": "2018-04-13",
            "opens":  "15:00:00",
            "closes":  "16:30:00"
        }
        ]
    }
}
</script>
```